# What does administering a vaccine intradeltoid mean?

Tags: vaccination, injections

In some places I have seen that while administering a vaccine it was written that it should be administered "intradeltoid". Does this mean intramuscular at the deltoid place or some different way of injecting?

Answer (score 4):

Intradeltoid is one of the routes of intramuscular administration, where the injection needle is administered into the deltoid muscle. The deltoid is a triangular-shaped muscle forming the rounded contour of the shoulder, with three points of origination, the lateral third of the clavicle, the acromion, and the posterior border of the spine of the scapula. It inserts into the deltoid tuberosity on the lateral shaft of the humerus.

> Procedure:
>
> - To locate the injection site, expose the shoulder and arm and identify the landmarks-acromion and deltoid tuberosity.
> - Palpate the acromion process by following the clavicle laterally where it articulates with the acromion at the acromioclavicular joint.
> - The deltoid tuberosity can be identified in the middle of the anterolateral surface of the humerus where the deltoid tapers into it.
> - Imagine an inverted triangle with its base just below the acromion process and opposite the tip of the triangle just above the deltoid tuberosity.
> - Select a spot for an injection in the middle of the triangle, about halfway between the base and tip of the triangle, stretch the skin, bunch up the muscle mass and inject at 90° to the skin surface. 
>     [image]
>
> Perhaps the most difficult aspect of injecting the deltoid involves the selection of appropriate needle length. The lengths suggested for use in children range from 16 to 32 mm depending on the age and size of the child. Note that the depth of connective tissue over the deltoid remains relatively consistent (~5 mm) in adolescents regardless of the individual's body-weight. In adults, the suggested range is 25-38 mm, again depending on patient size, with larger patients requiring longer needles.
>
> Limitation:
>
> A major limitation of this technique is the small size of its target area, which limits the number and volume of injections that can be administered.
>   [Source](http://www.ijsronline.net/article.asp?issn=2321-6662;year=2014;volume=4;issue=2;spage=25;epage=28;aulast=Barry#ref4)

https://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/70/6/944

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12173166